# is there a way to make images one size using css?

Tags: css

the issue is that i want the images to be the same size in the container but what i get is the container growing or shrinking to fit the image or the image stretching out of the container.

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <article class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Title</h4>                
      <p>something about the website</p>               
    </div>
    <div class="img-box">              
      <a href="#"><img src="./img/work-1.jpg" alt=""> 
      </a>                 
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  align-items: start;
  justify-items: start;
}



.card img {
  display: block;
}

.img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
img{
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: could you update the entire  code snippet here so that any one can help you out with debugging ? thanks.

Comment: the only other part of the code is two copies of the articles.